# Calculate the sum of the row values in a new dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this type of dataframe which represents the label given by each annotator (column name) for a mention in a text (index):

[image]

My goal is to transform this view, to get the sum of the annotators for a label given at each mention of the text, as:

[image]

Will anyone have a lead for doing this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df = df.set_index('<your date column name>').apply(pd.Series.value_counts, 1).fillna(0)
```

Comment: that's it thanks ! I just adapted so as not to group by annotators by removing the `.set_index ()` method from the example.